# c++ max_element every n element

Tags: c++, boost, std

Is there a way to find the max element in a container comparing every N elements and return the index. Using STL, BOOST, or... another lib?

with every N, I mean use the std::max_element, but change the increase in the for, from ++first, to first += n;

```
// based on std::max_element

#ifndef NEWTON_ALGORITHM_SEARCH_MAX_INDEX_HPP
#define NEWTON_ALGORITHM_SEARCH_MAX_INDEX_HPP

#include <iterator>

#include <newton/functional.hpp>

namespace newton {

  // SAME THAT STD::MAX_ELEMENT
  template<class ForwardIt, class Compare>
  const ForwardIt max_index(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Compare comp)
  {

    if ( newton::equal(first, last) ) // newton::equal is basically equivalent to std::equal_to
      return last;

    ForwardIt largest = first;
    while ( newton::not_equal(++first, last) )
      if (comp(*largest, *first))
        largest = first;

    return largest;

  }

  // possible names
  // max_index_some
  // max_index_every_n
  // max_index__n

  template<class ForwardIt, class Size, class Compare>
  const ForwardIt max_index_every_n(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Size n, Compare comp)
  {

    if ( newton::equal(first, last) )
      return last;

    ForwardIt largest = first;
    Size blocks = std::distance(first, last) / n; // integer blocks

    if ( newton::greater_equal(blocks, 1) ) {

      // if there are exacly N elements, can't sum example
      // v.size() = 10, first start in 0, so "0 += 10" is "10", but last index is "9"
      // but if mod >= 1, then index is at least 10, so can sum

      if ( newton::greater_equal( std::distance(first, last) % n, 1) ) {
        for (size_t i = 1; newton::less_equal(i, blocks); ++i, first += n) {

          if (comp(*largest, *first))
            largest = first;
        }
      }
      else {

        for (size_t i = 1; newton::less(i, blocks); ++i, first += n) {

          if (comp(*largest, *first))
            largest = first;
        }

      }

    }

    return largest;

  }

  template<class ForwardIt>
  const ForwardIt max_index(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)
  {
    return max_index(first, last, newton::structure::less());
  }
} // newton
```

if there is not, whats your solution to try to include it in a next STL version. [remember](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4Jl1fk3MkQ)

Comment: Maybe develop a container with a custom iterator?  I would surprised if there wasn't such a "stride" iterator available in boost or other library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using just Boost ("Range V2" so to speak):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5074cb30090ea5c3)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm_ext.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v(100);
    boost::iota(v, 0);

    int n = 17;
    auto it = boost::max_element(v | boost::adaptors::strided(n));

    std::cout << "max: " << *it << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
max: 85
```

### Alternative Usage

You don't have to use range algorithms and all. You can also pick as you require:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd0bcf2e4095a2cc)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/strided.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };

    auto v_ = boost::adaptors::stride(v, 7);
    auto it = std::max_element(v_.begin(), v_.end());

    std::cout << "max: " << *it << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
max: 8
```

Comment: But you execute the normal std::max_element, right? I mean, If I have a vector size 10⁶ and I want to see compare every 10⁵, I will compare all the 10⁶ when I could just compare 10?. If that happens, that is very... very... Just remember KISS.

Comment: I believe I've shown both. Executing the "normal algorithm" doesn't mean it visits all elements! That's why algorithms and containers were separated in C++. I other words, I'm not silly, and I answered your question, exactly like the other answer does (if you can afford a bleeding edge library like Range v3). Also, don't assume what is faster until you profile. Branch prediction, auto-vectorization and cache prefetch can surprise you

Comment: @MoisesRojo You're not even seeing the answers that you are reading. Just... try it for yourself: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f79f773b909d1f2 or even http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24b5038734b318dc and http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e32a5d4ecdfb494a. Note how in the second example seeing `++it` should be **exactly** the source of [your confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824956/c-max-element-every-n-element/49825992?noredirect=1#comment86668268_49825172). When you see the output, you will be enlightened. KISS indeed.

Comment: It's not personal the KISS, I'm more S that you.

Comment: Kiss it's a paradigm, not an attribute.

Comment: `private:
            void increment()
            {
                m_offset += m_stride;
            }
` yeah, Now I see how that it works.

Comment: I know the paradigm :) Separating abstractions (in this case, algorithms vs. ranges) is a good way to keep things simple. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), it would be:

```
auto r = v | ranges::view::stride(n);
auto it = ranges::max_element(r);
```

Comment: Is that efficient? `max_element(const ForwardRange& rng)
{
    BOOST_RANGE_CONCEPT_ASSERT(( ForwardRangeConcept<const ForwardRange> ));
    return std::max_element(boost::begin(rng), boost::end(rng));
}` I'm reading v2 and that is the code and is that, and the V3 say this `if(begin != end)
                    for(auto tmp = next(begin); tmp != end; ++tmp)
                        if(invoke(pred, invoke(proj, *begin), invoke(proj, *tmp)))
                            begin = tmp;
                return begin;` I don't want pass one by one element, each time. when i can `+= N`