# Iterating over a column of a multidimensional array with std::count_if()?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, stl

I have a multidimensional array of type double (`double someArray[10][20]`). I'd like to:

a) use `std::count_if()` to iterate over a single column of that array, returning the number of values greater than some number

b) also require that the row index of that number is within a certain range.

I know the basics of using `std::count_if` (i.e. I know how to iterate over, say, some vector and return values greater than/less than/equal to some value, for example), but I'm not sure how to do this over a column of a multidimensional array, or how to check that the index of the element also satisfies some condition.

Comment: Can you at least show us the definition of the multidimensinal array, and tell which column you want to check please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The array is 10 x 20. I'll end up calling std::count_if() more than once, checking a column chosen by some condition. So, I might want to check column 3 for values greater than, say, 7, with an row-index between, say, between 2 and 12. That's just an example. It more-or-less depends on an outside condition and user input.

Comment: So you have a `std::array<std::aray<double,20>,10>`? [Edit] your question instead of letting us guess please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have double myArray[10][20]

Comment: That's not a _"c++ standard array"_. but a raw c-style array.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes. Sorry, I see how that may have been confusing. I removed "standard".

Comment: Which index corresponds to rows, and which to columns?

Comment: [See if you can use this answer as a starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824956/c-max-element-every-n-element).  The data in a 2D array is contiguous, so you can apply any algorithm to the data easily with the begin and end iterators, i.e.. begin: `&somearray[0][0]`, end: `&somearray[9][20]`.  The stride count would simply be `20`.  So you just need to do a simple calculation to figure out the column starting address.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank's for the suggestion. I guess I'm not entirely understanding how this works, however (I'm probably just not thinking clearly, though, I've spent a lot of time on this today). Could you elaborate?

Comment: I will post an answer shortly, as long as the question isn't closed.  Basically you want a "stride iterator" instead of an iterator that goes through every element.  A 2D array has exactly the same layout as a 1D array -- there is no difference.  It's just that you have the convenient `[ ][ ]` syntax to denote the rows and columns.  Just take a 2D array, and instead of putting it in rows and columns, picture it as one continuous chain.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Ah, ok. I think I'm following more clearly now. I look forward to your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide and conquer.

- Use `count_if` to iterate over a single column of a multidimensional array, checking that the index of the row is within a certain range.

Break the problem into smaller pieces, until they are small enough to solve.

- Use `count_if`
- iterate over a single column of a multidimensional array
- checking that the index of the row is within a certain range

Hmm... that first task looks doable. Maybe the last. Back to division.

- Use `std::count_if`
- iterate:

  - over an array
  - but it's multidimensional
  - only one column matters
- checking that the index of the row is within a certain range

Iterating over an array is not hard, given [`std::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end). The multidimensional aspect looks scary, so let's wait on that and see how far we can get. For now, just plug "iterate over an array" into "use `count_if`".

```
std::count_if(std::begin(someArray), std::end(someArray), [](auto & element)
    { return ???; });
```

Hmm... the name `element` is not accurate is it? When `std::begin` is applied to `double [][20]`, only one dimension is consumed. The result of de-referencing is not `double` but `double [20]`, so `row` would be a more accurate name.

```
std::count_if(std::begin(someArray), std::end(someArray), [](auto & row)
    { return ???; });
```

The multidimensional aspect might have just taken care of itself. Can we focus on just one column? Let's assume a variable named `column` is the desired column index, and `target` can be the "some number" from the problem description.

```
std::count_if(std::begin(someArray), std::end(someArray), [column, target](auto & row)
    { return row[column] > target; });
```

So that leaves restricting the row index to a certain range. That is, iterate over the restricted range instead of over the entire array. Looks like a job for [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) and [`std::prev`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev). We'll just need two more variables to give us the range; let's use `from` and `to`.

```
// Check only the desired rows
auto start = std::next(std::begin(someArray), from);
auto stop =  std::prev(std::end(someArray), 9 - to);

return std::count_if(start, stop, [column, target](auto & row)
    { return row[column] > target; });
```

(I don't like that magic number `9`. Better would be `ROWS-1`, assuming suitable constants have been declared so that the array's declaration can become `double someArray[ROWS][COLS]`.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use [boost::range](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html), you can use the `count_if` with a stride count.

The reason why this will work is that an array, regardless of the number of dimensions, will store its data in contiguous memory, thus random-access iteration will work exactly as it would a one-dimensional array.

Thus the goal is to figure out the starting column (easy), and instead of iterating one element at a time forward as you would with the "normal" `std::count_if`, you want to iterate (in your case) `20` elements, since iterating that many will take you to the next row of the column you're interested in.

For a 2D array of `M x N` size, the starting and ending addresses you would use for the STL algorithm functions would be:

```
start: &array2D[0][0]
end (one item passed the end): &array[M-1][N]
```

Given this information, here is an example using `boost`:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/strided.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::adaptors;
    using namespace boost::assign;

    // declare and fill in the array with numbers starting from 0
    double someArray[10][20];
    std::iota(&someArray[0][0], &someArray[9][20], 0.0);

    // let's get the address of the start of the third column
    const double* startAddr = &someArray[0][2];  

   // here is the address of the end of the 2-dimensional array
    const double* endAddr = &someArray[9][20];  // add up the third column

    // create a SinglePass range consisting of the starting and ending address
    // plus the stride count
    auto str = std::make_pair(startAddr, endAddr) | strided(20);

    // count how many items in the third column are less than 60
    auto result = boost::range::count_if(str, [&](double val) { return val < 60; });
    std::cout << result;
}
```

Output:

```
3
```